# Missing empty Web Application template

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I  Just installed VS 2015 . Then I create New Project. Under Templates for C#/Web there is only one option and that is **ASP.NET Web Application**. That Template Creates a fully loaded application.

I need to know how to get Empty web app?

I tried to click on "Click here to go online and find templates" . but still, could not find the template for the C# empty web app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After select ASP.NET Web Application and click on "OK", you will see an empty template.

Comment: OK. I realize VS 2015 is a new software, this is clearly a VS 2015 bug. As it erratically hides or shows the  Empty Web App template.